# Green's Theorem: Integrate the $(\bigtriangledown \times F) \cdot k$

Tags: vector-analysis

$$F=(xy^2, y+x)$$
Integrate the $(\bigtriangledown \times F) \cdot k$ over the region of the first eightant that is bounded of the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=x$.
$$$$
Green's Theorem:
$$\int \int_R {(\bigtriangledown \times F) \cdot k}dxdy=\oint_S{F}d \sigma=\int_S{Mdx+Ndy}=\int_{S_1}{Mdx+Ndy}+\int_{S_2}{Mdx+Ndy}=\int_{S_1}{xy^2dx+(y+x)dy}+\int_{S_2}{xy^2dx+(y+x)dy}$$

[image]

$S_1: y=x$ $$\int_0^1{(x^3+2x)}dx=\frac{5}{4}$$
$S_2: y=x^2$ $$\int_0^1{(x^5+(x^2+x)2x)dx}=\frac{4}{3}$$
So $$\int \int_R {(\bigtriangledown \times F) \cdot k}dxdy=-\frac{5}{4}-\frac{4}{3}=-\frac{31}{12}$$

But in my textbook it is as followed:
$$\int \int_R {(\bigtriangledown \times F) \cdot k}dxdy=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{5}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$$
But why do we take these signs???

Comment: Greens theorem requires the curve S to be possitively oriented ( ie counterclockwise). When you integrate over $S_2$ you do it as x increases (from 0 to 1) but when you integrate over $S_1$ you should do it from 1 to 0.

Comment: @Francisco A ok!!Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm kind of new to multivariable calculus too so I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrals are done over *oriented* lines, surfaces, or other objects.  An integral done $\int_0^1$ is different from an integral done $\int_1^0$.  That's why they drew arrows on the picture, to tell you how each segment of curve is oriented.  You oriented $S_1$ correctly, but you oriented $S_2$ backwards.  Try fixing that sign and trying again.

Comment: I got!!Thanks a lot!!!